# C++ - Accessing private, nested iterator

Tags: c++

I can't figure out how to solve this problem. My iterator constructors need to be private, so I use the container to return an iterator, but it refuses to compile.

A.h

```
class A {
    public:
        class iterator {
            friend class A;
            public:
                virtual ~iterator();
                iterator operator++(int);
                iterator operator--(int);

            private:
                iterator(int index, A container);
        };


        iterator begin();
        iterator end();

};
```

A.cpp

```
A::iterator A::begin(){
    return iterator(0, *this);
}

A::iterator A::end(){
    return iterator(length(), *this);
}
```

I then call it like this:

```
for(A::iterator i = a.begin(); i != a.end(); i++)
    std::cout << *i;
```

But that last block says that "A::iterator is private within this context". I have a feeling the iterator constructor is only being called outside of begin(), but I don't know how to fix it. I'm fairly new to C++, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: First of all - constructor can't be private if you want to use it anywhere besides your class methods and functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the `iterator` class doesn't have a public constructor. You should implement a public copy-constructor (and probably a copy-assignment operator (see [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29))).

Comment: Thanks! Silly me, I had declared the copy constructor as private too, but it makes sense why it can't be.